# Sed an empty String and replace it

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, sh

i like to know how to replace an empty result  with `abc` for example in a long pipe.

So if i filter a big .txt file with `sed` and `grep` and other stuff. 
Is there a way that at the end of this pipe i replace an empty result?
So that if i dont find my pattern in the file i get an `abc`

I work in sh and want it included in the long pipe without  using special stuff.
I tried:

`cat myfile.txt | grep 'blabla.*' | sed 's/^$/abc/g'`

and

```
`cat myfile.txt | grep 'blabla.*' | sed 's//abc/g'`
```

.

Comment: What was wrong with the command you tried?

Comment: @EdMorton I think he can have a multi-line output with some empty lines amongst them.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are saying that if `grep` produces no matches, you want to see "abc".  I don't know if this counts as "special stuff", but you can do:

```
grep 'blabla.*' myfile.txt || echo abc
```

This will work fine in a pipeline:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 | { grep 'blabla.*' || echo abc; } | cmd3 | cmd4
```

In fact, it also works just fine to put more complex logic in a pipeline, although you don't see this style very often:

```
cmd1 |
if grep blabla.*; then : ; else echo abc; fi |
cmd2
```

Comment: Is there a way where i can make it when the pipe ends with sed and not with grep?

Comment: I want to check this at the very end. So if also the last command at the end (lets say sed) gives me a empty string i echo abc

Comment: Try, `arbitrary cmds | sed ... | { grep . || echo abc; }`

Answer (score 2):

I would use a single `awk` command:

```
awk '/blabla/{print;found=1}END{if(!found){print "not found"}}' myfile.txt
```

Comment: I want to make it without commands like ark. Like cmd|cmd|cmd(that if empty til here echo "abc")

Comment: Why do you want that? `awk` is meant for that.

Comment: Cause i want to know. I know awk but want to know how to solve without

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
tee >(read || echo "abc")
```

Explanation:
You can look for empty input with

```
pipeline_with_sed | grep -q . || echo "abc"
```

This has different problems.
When the output has empty lines, it is not empty. So you should test for any data:

```
pipeline_with_sed | read || echo "abc"
```

This will give your "abc" for empty output of the pipeline.
Now you want to see the original output when something is there.
With `tee` you can redirect the output to a file and another process.
And redirecting to a file can also be replaced to writing to another program.

```
pipeline_with_sed | tee >(read || echo "abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/blabla/q;$!d;cabc
```

If string found print it and quit. Otherwise at end of the file change the last line to `abc`.